# m4a file plays with avplayer but not avaudioplayer

Tags: ios, swift

This strange occurrence happens when I build my app on my iPhone. AVAudioPlayer does nothing when I attempt to play the file.

AVPlayer on the other hand plays the file just fine.

I'd like to use AVAudioPlayer as it has audio mix settings. The same AVAudioPlayer can play mp3 files just find so I haven't set it up incorrectly.

working:

`player = AVPlayer(url: m4aFile)`

vs

not working:

`player = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: m4aFile)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks information but maybe you're forgetting to call `prepareToPlay` when using `AVAudioPlayer`.

Comment: no. that's not my issue. I'm well aware that I need to do that.  I said that I can ply mp3 files using avaudioplayer just not m4a files. which means it seems to be some kind of difference in format support?

Comment: AVAudioPlayer should support m4a since its supported by Core Audio. Is m4aFile a local file? Could you add a bit more context to your code? Like where the file comes from and how you begin playback .

Comment: certainly. I'm pulling the file from the documents directory defined in the code:

Comment: FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

Comment: then I'm using the contents of that directory to return all files within the directory and add them to an array.
 try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: path, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])

Comment: I'd suggest implementing the `AVAudioPlayer` delegate to see if any error is being thrown in `audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur`

Comment: no error being thrown put it in a try and catch and it doesn't seem to have any issue either.

Comment: I doubt this will work since mp3 works but you could try setting a category for `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()` after `prepareToPlay` just before play